# Create Record In Reference Table

Tags: sql, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables in SQL.
A table, called `users_info`, have a `FOREIGN KEY`, that references to another table, called `users`, column `id`.

When I create a record in `users`, I want to create a new record with only id of the record, and id of the user (in column with `FOREIGN KEY`).

Do I have to do two times `INSERT INTO`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle,...?

Comment: I use PhpMyAdmin and InnoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is a bit strange, i don't understand the logic behind the process you're looking for. If you systematically create an entry in `users_info` when you create a new entity in `users`, why are you using two different tables?

It can be useful if you provide us the structure of your tables and a sample of data in order to clarify your logic.

As answer to your question, yes there is the need of two `INSERT` statement for that but you're not forced to write both statements each time. I suggestion you to take a look to [Triggers](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/).

If you create a trigger `AFTER INSERT` on your table `users` you'll be able to automatise the insertion into table `users_info` as desired. The mechanism will be as following:

1. Insert a new user in table `users`
2. The `AFTER INSERT` action is triggered
3. The trigger create the appropriate reference in table `users_info`

Hope this will help you.